# Help making a specific segment

Tags: tikz-styles

I'm pretty new to tikz and I have no idea how to draw this:

u(x,t) must be in the middle of the segment and each other point is separated by a distance "h", there is  1/2 above the middle of each point.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Serch -- Welcome --please see the answer below and accept if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (-6,0) -- (6,0) ; %edit here for the axis
        \foreach \x/\y in  {-6/{$U(X-2h,f)$},-3/{$U(X-h,f)$},0/{$U(X,f)$},3/{$U(X+h,f)$},6/{$U(X+2h,f)$}} % edit here for the vertical lines
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt)node[below] {\y};
        \foreach \x/\y in {-6/-3,-3/0,0/3,3/6}
        \draw[bend left,looseness=1.4, shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt, blue, thick](\x,0)to node[ label=90: 1/2]{}(\y,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks!