# Help making a specific 2D segment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I few days ago, I asked on this forum for [a way to draw a 1-d segment in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/591598/118712). And you guys were of great help.

I tried to adapt the code I was given, in order to draw the same segment but in two dimensions, but I was unable to do it. May I ask for your help again?
[image: help]

This is the code I used for the 1D image:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-6,0) -- (6,0) ; 
    \foreach \x/\y in  {-6/{$x-2h$},-3/{$x-h$},0/{$x$},3/{$x+h$},6/{$x+2h$}}  
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt)node[below] {\y};
    \foreach \x/\y in {-6/-3,-3/0,0/3,3/6}
    \draw[bend left,looseness=1.4, shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt, blue, thick](\x,0)to node[ label=90: 1/2]{}(\y,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hint: use coordinates with zero `x` and only values in `y` (eg. `(0,6)`). Also, replace `below` by `left`, for example. In other words, you have to *think rotated*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sigur sugested, just switch the x and y values:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={font=\strut},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \draw (-6,0) -- (6,0) ; 
        \foreach \x/\y in  {-6/{$x-2h$},-3/{$x-h$},3/{$x+h$},6/{$x+2h$}}  
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt)node[below] {\y};
        \foreach \x/\y in {-6/-3,-3/0,0/3,3/6}
        \draw[bend left,looseness=1.4, shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt, blue, thick](\x,0)to node[above, blue]{1/2}(\y,0);
        
        \node[below right] at (3pt,-3pt) {$x$};
        
        \draw (0,-6) -- (0,6) ; 
        \foreach \x/\y in  {-6/{$x-2h$},-3/{$x-h$},3/{$x+h$},6/{$x+2h$}}  
        \draw[shift={(0,\x)},color=black] (-3pt,0pt) -- (3pt,0pt)node[right] {\y};
        \foreach \x/\y in {-6/-3,-3/0,0/3,3/6}
        \draw[bend left,looseness=1.4, shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt, blue, thick](0,\x)to node[left, blue]{1/2}(0,\y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]